# ListView with Spannable Strings

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity which shows a Users Twitter timeline in a List View. When I click on either a Hastag (#example), a Twitter Handle (@example) or a URL (http://www.example.com) I just for now want it to bring up a toast message saying what you have clicked on.

**The problem that I have is that this only works on a listView that has a url link in it. If there is no url in a particular item, I cannot click on any on any of the other types of links (# and @)**

Here is the code making the links in the text (_text is a Spannable String)

```
public void createLinksInText(String text) {
        int end = 0;

        //first check for '@' usernames
        int start = text.indexOf("@");

        while (start >= 0) {

            end = text.substring(start).indexOf(" ") + start;
            if (end < 0 || end < start) end = text.length();
            _text.setSpan(new TwitterHandleClickableSpan(), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            start = text.indexOf("@", start + 1);
        }

        //then check for '#' hashtags
        start = text.indexOf("#");

        while (start >= 0) {

            end = text.substring(start).indexOf(" ") + start;
            if (end < 0 || end < start) end = text.length();
            _text.setSpan(new HashtagClickableSpan(), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            start = text.indexOf("#", start + 1);
        }

        //finally, check for links
        start = text.indexOf("http");
        if (start < 0)
            start = text.indexOf("www");

        while (start >= 0) {

            end = text.substring(start).indexOf(" ") + start;
            if (end < 0 || end < start) end = text.length();
            _text.setSpan(new URLClickableSpan(), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            start = text.indexOf("http", start + 1);
            if (start < 0)
                start = text.indexOf("www", start + 1);
        }


    }
```

Here are the implementations of the clickable spans for each link.

```
class HashtagClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan { //clickable span

        public void onClick(View textView) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(_context, "Hashtag clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.hyperlinkColor));//set text color
        }
    }

    class TwitterHandleClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan { //clickable span

        public void onClick(View textView) {


            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(_context, "Twitter Handle clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.hyperlinkColor));//set text color
        }
    }

    class URLClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan { //clickable span

        public void onClick(View textView) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(_context, "URL clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.hyperlinkColor));//set text color
        }
    }
```

Here is the **XML** for the Listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/statusImage"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/statusText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColorLink="@color/hyperlinkColor"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/statusImage"
        android:autoLink="web"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@id/statusText"
        android:id="@+id/statusDateText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/statusImage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I take out the **android:autolink="web"**, then I cannot click on any of the created links.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to get the TextView which was storing my links and add the following.

```
text_line1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```